# Is it possible to setup remote SDK in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, raspberry-pi

I really like IntelliJ IDEA IDE, However I need to work w/ Raspberry Pi. Is it possible to setup remote SDK like in Netbeans?

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-embedded.html

Comment: Does Netbeans support remote debugging or is it just upload of the finished application?

Comment: Remote running, debugging, everything.

Comment: So..., nobody knows the answer?